Convert adress to coordinates
I got a little problem with changing the value of an object. I have got the following code and want to change the value of the object.
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var address = ""
    
    @State private var object = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(object)")
            TextField("Type address", text: $address)
            Button("Change object") {
                getLocation(address: address, object: object)
                print(object)
            }
            
        }
    }
    func getLocation (address: String, object: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D{
        let address = address 
        let object = object
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            self.object.latitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0
            self.object.longitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0
        }
        
        return object
        
    }
}


The app displays the correct value of the address, but in the "print" command the default data is shown.
How do I change the value?

geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) {...} is an asynchronous function, look up what is means. There are lots of info on that and how to use them. Hint your return object is returned before the self.object.latitude etc are updated.

You totally got it wrong, since object is a @State it will automatically notify when it changes, and you don't need to pass it as a parameter within the function, it's meaningless. geocodeAddressString also supports async await.

open func geocodeAddressString(_ addressString: String) async throws -> [CLPlacemark]

Try this:
var body: some View {
    ...
    Button("Change object") {
       Task {
            do {
                let placemark = try await getLocation(address: address).first
                self.object.latitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0
                self.object.longitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0
            } catch {
                //Handle error if needed
            }
        }
    }
}

func getLocation(address: String) async throws -> [CLPlacemark] {
    try await CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address)
}

